# Php calling javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

I can do that? Im trying to call a javascript function after conditional php "if"

```
<script type="text\javascript">
functioncall = (function(id){
   alert(id);
});
</script>

<?php
if(isset($_get['id']){
   echo "<script>functioncall({$_get['id']});</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: `$_GET` needs to be capitalized, as it's a superglobal.

Comment: You know difference between server side and client side right?

Comment: Of course you can output code to the client depending on a condition …

Comment: **Danger**: Echoing data from the URL directly into the page exposes you to XSS attacks.

Comment: Yes,  you can do that. Why not try it?

Comment: you can pass by querystring like a link or by a submit(form)

Comment: You can try echo "<![CDATA [functioncall({$_GET['id']});</script>]]>";

Comment: I tryied but not worked... =/

Comment: @ValeryStatichny — only in `application/xhtml+xml` which almost nobody uses and even fewer people get any measureable benefit from.

Comment: thanks for negative to my question, obviously that group is just for pro developers, and not to students. THANKS!!!!

Comment: Yes @Robert, and how it help here?

Comment: @Quentin, I read about what here http://support.envato.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/472/85/wordpress-theme-submission-requirements  Should cdata tag be commented regarding to this situation ?

Comment: @ValeryStatichny — XHTML shouldn't be used, then CDATA markers should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

Use $_GET instead of $_get in php condition, I have corrected some of the errors like script tag script type, and PHP $_GET

```
    <script type="text/javascript">         
        functioncall = (function(id){
               alert(id);
        });
   </script>

 <?php
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
       echo "<script>functioncall('{$_GET['id']}');</script>";
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just using JS ?

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}
```

And do like...

```
var id = getQueryVariable('id');
if(id) {
    alert(id);
}
```

Credit : http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/

Answer (score 0):

As Quentin said you are exposed to XSS attacks. Don't ever put anything into your page from GET variables (url variables) - 'id' in your case.

Anyways, if you want to call a function based on a php condition, you can do something like this:

```
<script type="text\javascript">
functioncall = (function(id){
   alert(id);
});
</script>

<?php
if(condition-goes-here){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
   functioncall(<?php echo 'Put in your php data' ?>);
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

I haven't checked it, hope it should work. If your condition returns false, your function call will not be put into your page.

It's not a good practice though.

Comment: I understand... but how is the best way to pass a parameter to javascript without "echo $_GET?"?

Comment: For example, you can query the database for some data, and use that data as a parameter to javascript... You can pass any php variable to javascript unless it's a GET and POST variables (atleast before validating them)

Comment: Yes, i searched about expose superglobals, initially, my idea was pass an id to my ajax function query db and return the form input text values trought jquery to update data after edit the text values of my form.